# How to get first cell in a tablerow with Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a simple table like this one:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td> A </td>
   <td> B </td>
   <td> C </td>
   <td><input type="button"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> 1 </td>
   <td> 2 </td>
   <td> 3 </td>
   <td><input type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I click the button a function takes place which gets the first character in the first table row. So in row 1 that would be "A", in row 2 that would be "1". None of the rows or cells have unique ID's, so can't use those.

Right now I was trying to do something like:

```
charValue = $(this).parent()first().text();
```

But for some reason when I do that I get "ABC" and not just "A".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `find` after `closest("tr")`

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td").first().text();
```

Or alternatively `td:first`

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this code

```
$("input").click(function() {
  // Bad practice 
  //var charValue = $(this).parent().parent().children().first().text();

  //god practice
  var charValue = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text();

  alert(charValue)
})
```

Comment: Chaining `parent()` calls is never a good idea. Use `closest()` instead

Comment: This is just for understanding cause guys was using parent so that way i am using parent.

Comment: I would argue that if you want people to understand something you should teach them the best method, not the worst.

Comment: @PankajBisht bad *

Comment: Don't worry, I knew stringing parents wasn't a good idea but I couldn't really think of another way to do it. Thanks for showing me the proper way! And still thanks for trying to help @PankajBisht. :)